# Tooltip text for html table data in css

Tags: html, css, tooltip, html-table

I tried to make a tooltip text when I hover over a specific table column in my table but its not working. I don't want to use JS or Jquery. Any ideas how to make it work in CSS? Full working table row in JsFiddle

I tried this: http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_tooltip.asp But its not working in my code for some reason. Any ideas?

JsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/6tLmn9sd/

```
<div class="content">
<div class="header">
</div>
<a name="172016">
<!--1. riadok H-->
<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0">
<tr>
 <th width="50px">C. u.</th>
 <th width="30px">Zobrazit</th>
 <th width="30px">Typ</th>
 <th width="200px">Cislo/Meno</th>
 <th width="600px">Popis</th>
 <th width="130px">System</th>
 <th width="100px">Dopad/Symptom</th>
 <th width="100px">Dátum zadania</th>
 <th width="100px">Dátum vzniku</th>
 <th width="100px">Datum Verifikacie</th>
 <th width="80px">Ukoncenie</th>
 <th width="500px">Komentár</th>
 <th width="100px">Dátum</th>
 <th width="60px">Počet</th>
</tr>
<!--2. riadok D-->
<tr>
 <td style="text-align:center;background-color: #d0f5f6">100</td>
 <td style="text-align:center">X</td>
 <td style="text-align:center">C </td>
 <td>DOBRIKOVA/DURACKA</td>
 <td><div class="tooltip">Gefco PC nasa siet CD vs finalne riesenie internet gefco pc CORAIL     <span class="tooltiptext">ked sa vytvara uplne novu hypotheza tak nefunguje vyber tlaciarni a globalny export tiez NOK (nepouzivame)</span> </div></td>
 <td>CORAIL/CONSO</td>
 <td></td>
 <td class="DZ">06/07/2016</td>
 <td class="DZ">06/07/2016</td>
 <td class="DZ">06/07/2016</td>
 <td style="text-align:center">OK</td>
 <td>ked sa vytvara uplne novu hypotheza tak nefunguje vyber tlaciarni a globalny export tiez NOK (nepouzivame)</td>
 <td style="text-align:center">07/07/2016</td>
 <td style="text-align:center">2</td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't add any CSS to make your tooltip show up on hover. Besides, I would recommend you to move your `.tooltip` class to  `<td>` tag. Please see the modified code:
https://jsfiddle.net/cbqfqmLc/

Comment: I added it into jsfiddle, on this side i was unable to because of some reason ctrl+k didnt work, sorry :)

Comment: So, did my answer help you?

Comment: Yes it did but there is a problem. When I add longer text it will create another line and that line will not be visible. Any idea how to make it above the table so it can go over collums if necesary?

Comment: You just need to remove `overflow: hidden` from the `th, td` css selector